# Integration of first-order differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading a book in electrical engineering and in one example they are skipping steps and I'm not sure how they integrate the equation:
$$ \frac{dv}{dt} + \frac{v}{RC} = 0 $$
which they rewrite as: $$ \frac{dv}{v} = -\frac{dt}{RC}$$

Integrating the function gives: $$ \ln(v) = -\frac{t}{RC} + \ln(A) $$
Where $A$ is the constant. $\frac{1}{v}$ gives $\ln(v)$, but I don't get the right hand side. Why not just '$A$'?

Thanks.

Comment: $A$ and $\ln(A)$ are the same, since A can be anything (including a complex number). They are using $\ln(A)$ so the next step of raising everything to an exponential is more clear. 

I personally wouldn't do it like that. I would instead note that $e^A$ is the same as $A$ in the next step.

Comment: a constant is a constant

Comment: Okay, thanks. It makes sense, it's been a while since I did calculus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author is thinking ahead in the problem.
If we write $\ln(v) = -\frac{t}{RC} + B$, we can then exponentiate both sides of this equation:
$$e^{\ln(v)} = e^{-\frac{t}{RC}} e^B$$
so if $B=\ln(A)$ then
$$v = A e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}$$
We can always find some $A$ for which $B=\ln(A)$ because the range of $\ln$ is all real numbers.
The only reason they did this was to simplify the final result. It isn't a spooky integration trick, don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it helps to introduce the constant of integration in this way because when you look at the LHS it is ugly. But seriously by introducing it this way you can learn a lot more about the system for e.g. you can rewrite it as $ln(v)-ln(A)=-t/RC$ which can be re-written as $v/A=e^{-t/RC}$ and hence you can see $v/a$ decays over time or whatever it may be. Make sense?